# front-page.php includes a placeholder text field. How to get rid of it?

Tags: templates

I have used front-page.php as a custom template for my site's home page.
The page includes a page editor field even though I have coded the template entirely to use ACF Pro custom fields. The editor is also set to be not shown in ACF settings.

The unwanted wysiwyg editor has this text included by default:
Use this static Page to test the Theme's handling of the Front Page template file.This is the Front Page content. Use this static Page to test the Front Page output of the Theme. The Theme should properly handle both Blog Posts Index as Front Page and static Page as Front Page.If the site is set to display the Blog Posts Index as the Front Page, then this text should not be visible. If the site is set to display a static Page as the Front Page, then this text may or may not be visible. If the Theme does not include a front-page.php template file, then this text should appear on the Front Page when set to display a static Page. If the Theme does include a front-page.php template file, then this text may or may not appear.

How and where do I get rid of this?

Comment: This text, from the WordPress Theme Unit Test data? https://github.com/WPTRT/theme-unit-test/blob/master/themeunittestdata.wordpress.xml#L1511 (Why did you base your site on that?) Do you have an item 'Front Page' under the 'Pages' menu in your admin dashboard? Or you could make one of the configuration changes the text suggests, depending on what you want there!

Comment: Yes, that is the text which is appearing. I started a new project using a new setup, creating a theme from scratch, so I imported the test data. Should have realised it was coming from there, but I though I had deleted all of that data. This makes sense now.

Thanks, I had thought the editor was set to hidden in ACF Pro but that still needed to be done.